# OPENXML in Sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a XML structure

```
"<AttachVersion><Version>1</Version><Version>2</Version><Version>3</Version><Version>4</Version></AttachVersion>"
```

### I want to get the "Version" values using "OPENXML".

I know it can be done with the below query.

```
DECLARE @AttachVersions XML
SET @AttachVersions = '<AttachVersion><Version>1</Version><Version>2</Version><Version>3</Version><Version>4</Version></AttachVersion>'
SELECT ParamValues.[Version].value('.', 'VARCHAR(10)') AS [Version] FROM @AttachVersions.nodes('/AttachVersion/Version') as ParamValues([Version])
```

### We can not change the input parameter to XML.

I know there is an alternate way to get the with "OPENXML" if it's an attribute value. Here's the sample code

```
DECLARE @FileterOptions VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @FileterOptions = '<AttachVersion><Version Value="1" /><Version Value="2" /><Version Value="3" /><Version Value="4" /></AttachVersion>'

DECLARE @AttachVersionHandle INT

CREATE TABLE #tmpAttachVersionList
(
    [Value] INT
)

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @AttachVersionHandle OUTPUT, @FileterOptions

INSERT #tmpAttachVersionList ( [Value] )
    SELECT [Value] FROM OPENXML( @AttachVersionHandle, '//Version' ) WITH #tmpAttachVersionList

SELECT * FROM #tmpAttachVersionList

DROP TABLE #tmpAttachVersionList
```

---

Is it possible to get the "Version" values with OPENXML using `"XPath"`?

Comment: Could you please format your text to make it more readable?

Comment: Sorry.. I just updated

Comment: "We can not change the input parameter to XML" - can you be clear on exactly what *can* be changed, then, in this instance? Even if you can't change a parameter definition, casting a `varchar(max)` to `xml` is trivial to do. Is that also not an option?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever As I mentioned, it can be achieved with the input type as XML instead of VARCHAR(MAX). I just want to know is it possible to do with OPENXML as input parameter as VARCHAR(MAX)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.. Here's the query

```
DECLARE @AttachVersion VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @AttachVersionHandle INT
SET @AttachVersion = '<AttachVersion><Version>1</Version><Version>2</Version><Version>3</Version><Version>4</Version></AttachVersion>'

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @AttachVersionHandle OUTPUT, @AttachVersion

SELECT [Value] FROM OPENXML( @AttachVersionHandle, '/AttachVersion/Version') WITH (VALUE INT '.')
```